# Move around cube using WASD in Pygame?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

The problem is when I hit a key the camera continues to move rather than when I hold the key it moves and then it stops somewhere. How do I fix this? This is my code for the project I import the opengl module and I create vertexs edges and surfaces for the cube. I am trying to use pygame and pyopengl to create a cube where I can  move around the cube with WASD movements.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verts = (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1),
)

edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7),
)

surfaces = (
    (0, 1, 2, 3),
    (3, 2, 7, 6),
    (6, 7, 5, 4),
    (1, 5, 7, 2),
    (4, 5, 1, 0),
    (4, 0, 3, 6),
)

colors = (
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
)

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    x = 0
    for surface in surfaces:
        x+=1
        for vertex in surface:
            glColor3fv(colors[x])
            glVertex3fv(verts[vertex])
    glEnd()
    
    
    
    
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verts[vertex])


    glEnd()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (1280, 720)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)
    pos = 0.0
    back = 0.0
    glTranslatef(pos, 0.0, back)
    while True:

        pressed_left = False
        pressed_right = False
        pressed_up = False
        pressed_down = False
        glTranslatef(pos, 0.0, back)

        x_move = 0
        y_move = 0

        #camera
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    pressed_left = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    pressed_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    pressed_down = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    pressed_up = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    pressed_left = False
                    print('off key')
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    pressed_right = False
                    print('off key')
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    pressed_up = False
                    print('off key')
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    pressed_down = False
                    print('off key')

        if pressed_left == True:
            pos = -0.1
            print('key left')
        elif pressed_right == True:
            pos = 0.1
            print('key right')
        elif pressed_up == True:
            back = 0.1
            print('key up')
        elif pressed_down == True:
            back = -0.1
            print('key down')
        else:
            pos = pos
            back = back


        #glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legacy OpenGL matrix transformations like [`glTranslatef`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glTranslate.html) do not set a transformation. The matrix operations define a new transformation matrix and multiply the current transformation matrix by the new matrix.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released.
[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement when a key is hold down:

```py
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (1280, 720)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(90, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    pos, back = 0.0, -5.0
    glTranslatef(pos, 0.0, back)
    
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            glTranslatef(-0.1, 0.0, 0.0)
            print('key left')
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            glTranslatef(0.1, 0.0, 0.0)
            print('key right')
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.1, 0.0)
            print('key up')
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            glTranslatef(0.0, -0.1, 0.0)
            print('key down')

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]